# How to interface raspberry pi and plc?

Tags: gpio, python, linux

I am doing a project on controlling the plc by using raspberry pi. Any one please suggest some sample coding and tutorial regarding this project.
am already finished a coding part to connect a control  model to control plc. Now I am struck with how to interface and gathering information from plc to pi.

Comment: Which PLC? I think some of them can do I2C.

Answer (score 2):

There are many different ways to interface with a PLC. Depending on what protocols they communicate with.

Here's some links on two of those protocols

Step7 for Siemens PLCS S7-200,S7-1200 and S7-1500: http://simplyautomationized.blogspot.com/2014/12/raspberry-pi-getting-data-from-s7-1200.html

Modbus TCP for many others: using pymodbus this blogger was turning on a PLC from his pi built lightswitch:
http://simplyautomationized.blogspot.com/2013/09/home-automation-project-part-3-webapp.html

Hope that helps.

**Update**:

Been able to control a Koyo DL-06 with ethernet as well:
http://simplyautomationized.blogspot.com/2015/04/raspberry-pi-getting-data-from-koyo-dl.html

Answer (score -1):

You can use new PLC platform Speedplc for Raspberry Pi.

https://www.fultek.com.tr/en/speed-plc/

Comment: In keeping with [our policy regarding informationless link-only answers](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538), if this post is not edited to contain information that can stand as an answer, however minimal, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community.